# Possible bug in perpage package. TexLive 2022

Tags: footnotes, bugs, perpage

I'm using XeLaTeX, and the version is:

```
$ xelatex -version | grep 'TeX Live'
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022)
```

When I use the perpage package with the memoir class, the footnote on the first page of a chapter start with the number 2. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{perpage}

\MakePerPage{footnote}

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

some text\footnote{first footnote}

\clearpage

more text\footnote{another footnote}

\chapter{}

even more text\footnote{yet another footnote}

\end{document}
```

and this is the output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The book class shows the same problem. Is this a bug?

Comment: This happens also with `report`, `scrreprt` and `scrbook` and pdfLaTeX. Seems to only affect `\chapter` and not `\section`.

Comment: that is an rather old bug in perpage, I get it already in texlive 2015. Use `\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}` instead, footmisc contains a patch for it, see https://github.com/FrankMittelbach/fmitex-footmisc/issues/3

Comment: `footmisc` seems to interfere with `memoir`'s own footnote formatting, rendering changes in `\footmarkwidth` `\footmarksep` and `\footparindent` ineffective. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use `\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}`. Alternatively you can hook to `\@chapter` to lower the counter:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{perpage}

\MakePerPage{footnote}
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/@chapter/after}{\setcounter{footnote}{0}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{}

some text\footnote{first footnote} other text\footnote{second footnote}

\clearpage

more text\footnote{another footnote} more other text\footnote{second other footnote}

\chapter{}

even more text\footnote{yet another footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

As stated by zzjing in his comment, `\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}` interferes with `memoir` footnote formatting.

On the other hand, Marijn's answer seems not to work with `hyperref` (I get warnings saying `Use of \Hy@org@chapter doesn't match its definition.`).

So, I tried to use the patch proposed in https://github.com/FrankMittelbach/fmitex-footmisc/issues/3 (as suggested by Ulrike Fischer's comment):

```
\makeatletter
  \def\@stpelt#1{\global\csname c@#1\endcsname \m@ne
    \stepcounter{#1}%
    \setcounter{#1}{0}%
  }

\def\pp@cl@end@iii\stepcounter#1\setcounter#2#3{}
\makeatother
```

It works for me with `memoir` and `hyperref`